# How to Import .bson file format on mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I've exported the database on the server using `mongodump` command and dump is stored in `.bson` file. I need to import that in my local server using `mongorestore` command. However it's not working. What is the correct `mongorestore` command and what are the other `tools to restore db`?

Answer (score 466):

It's very simple to import a **.bson** file:

```
mongorestore -d db_name -c collection_name /path/file.bson
```

Incase only for a **single collection**.Try this:

```
mongorestore --drop -d db_name -c collection_name /path/file.bson
```

For restoring the complete folder exported by `mongodump`:

```
mongorestore -d db_name /path/
```

***Note:*** If you have enabled authentication use the below syntax:

```
mongorestore -u username --authenticationDatabase admin -d db_name -c collection_name /path/file.bson
```

Comment: Also useful for the bson file exported via `mongoexport` if you're only exporting single collections. `mongoimport` was giving me "invalid character" errors. Thanks!

Comment: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:16

Comment: Maybe you can add that these commands are to be run from command prompt and not from mongo console. That would help new users

Comment: Adding to this answer. For those that want to remotely restore a bson file.
`Mongorestore -h [host] -u [user] -p [pass] -d [database] -c [collection] [bson file]`

Comment: Thank, JERRY! I have some problem importing or restoring some .bson and .json files and appreciate if you could take a look https://stackoverflow.com/q/51394444/156458.

Comment: Thanks it worked for my complete folder after extrackting from tar.gz

Comment: Run the following from command line and you should be in the Mongo bin directory.

Answer (score 67):

`mongorestore` is the tool to use to import bson files that were dumped by `mongodump`.

From the [docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-mongorestore):

> mongorestore takes the output from mongodump and restores it.

Example:

```
# On the server run dump, it will create 2 files per collection
# in ./dump directory:
# ./dump/my-collection.bson
# ./dump/my-collection.metadata.json
mongodump -h 127.0.0.1 -d my-db -c my-collection

# Locally, copy this structure and run restore.
# All collections from ./dump directory are picked up.
scp user@server:~/dump/**/* ./
mongorestore -h 127.0.0.1 -d my-db
```

Comment: Do I need to keep the `dump/dbName/collectionName.bson` folder structure? I used `mongodump`, but now I want to import it using `mongorestore` on a remote Linux box.

Comment: @Kevin: I'm not sure, to be honest, but I would assume so. Use an FTP program to transfer the files along with the folder structure?

Comment: I was able to successfully import a mongo db using a non-"dump" folder name:`mongorestore --collection people --db accounts myDump/accounts/people.bson`

Answer (score 46):

```
bsondump collection.bson > collection.json
```

and then

```
mongoimport -d <dbname> -c <collection> < collection.json
```

Comment: Note the warning from MongoDB's [import-export documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/import-export/): `mongoimport and mongoexport do not reliably preserve all rich BSON data types because JSON can only represent a subset of the types supported by BSON. As a result, data exported or imported with these tools may lose some measure of fidelity.`

Comment: Yep. This messes up Chinese/Japanese characters.

Answer (score 16):

Just for reference if anyone is still struggling with mongorestore.

You have to run monogorestore in terminal/command prompt and not in mongo console.

```
$ mongorestore -d db_name /path_to_mongo_dump/
```

for more details you can visit official documentations

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/

Answer (score 11):

Run the following from command line and you should be in the Mongo bin directory.

`mongorestore -d db_name -c collection_name path/file.bson`

Answer (score 9):

You have to run this mongorestore command via cmd and not on Mongo Shell... Have a look at below command on...

Run this command on cmd (not on Mongo shell)

```
>path\to\mongorestore.exe -d dbname -c collection_name path\to\same\collection.bson
```

Here `path\to\mongorestore.exe` is path of `mongorestore.exe` inside bin folder of mongodb. dbname is name of databse. `collection_name` is name of collection.bson. `path\to\same\collection.bson` is the path up to that collection.

Now from mongo shell you can verify that database is created or not (If it does not exist, database with same name will be created with collection).

Answer (score 6):

If your access remotely you can do it

for bson:

```
mongorestore --host m2.mongodb.net --port 27016 --ssl --username $user --password $password --authenticationDatabase $authdb -d test -c people "/home/${USER}/people.bson"
```

for bson compressed in .gz (gzip) format:

```
mongorestore --host m2.mongodb.net --port 27016 --ssl --username $user --password $password --authenticationDatabase $authdb -d test -c people --gzip --dir "/home/${USER}/people.bson.gz"
```

Answer (score 4):

In mongodb 3.0 or above, we can specify database name to restore. Assuming that you are standing at the root directory that contains **bson** files

```
./
a.bson
b.metadata.bson
...
```

The script would be

```
for FILENAME in *; do mongorestore -d <db_name> -c "${FILENAME%.*}" $FILENAME; done
```

Comment: This was very useful! Thanks!

Comment: Nice. You may want to filter by just the bson files by restricting to `for FILENAME in *.bson`. Helps avoid attempting to mongorestore everything else.

Answer (score 1):

mongorestore -d db_name /path/

make sure you run this query in bin folder of mongoDb

C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin -

then run this above command.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this:

```
mongorestore -d databasename -c file.bson fullpath/file.bson
```

1.copy the file path and file name from properties (try to put all bson files in different folder),
2.use this again and again with changing file name only.