# BSON file in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, bson

I try to translate my BSON file in the common JSON format. After using of

```
bsondump ./<path>/test.bson > ./<path>/test.json
```

I got next error

```
SyntaxError: invalid flag after regular expression (shell):1
```

I already read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770498/how-to-import-bson-file-format-on-mongodb), but couldn't open BSON file

Comment: This is not possible. BSON has additional field types. JSON is a limited subset of BSON, so to say.

Comment: I probably just have the old version of mongodb. Do update now

Comment: ok, I really had just the old version. After update everything is good.

Comment: You should make sure that you have valid JSON, which I doubt.

Comment: I have got valid JSON, already tested. Thanks