# Importing and querying a mongodb bson file from external harddrive

Tags: r, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to mongodb. I have a bson file(collect.bson) and it is on my external hard drive, very large about 200 GB and I want to run a query and i want to do that from my terminal. Do I need to create a database first in order to do that? Considering the fact that it is such a large file I don't how much space it will consume. I installed mongobd from my terminal and I was curious how I can proceed to extract the attributes and columns into a csv/R? Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: First you have to import bson file to your database: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770498/how-to-import-bson-file-format-on-mongodb. Then you can send queries from R using mongolite package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mongolite/mongolite.pdf

Comment: Thanks, does it take a lot of space, i have never used a database, the bson file size is around 200GB, do you know how much space it takes and can i store in an external hard drive instead of my laptop? any thoughts? thanks so much!

Comment: You have to import it to local database, that is c drive. I am not sure how much space you need but less than 200 GB. You can also import it to d drive or any other drive on which you have more space.