# How can I import bson and json files into MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have following `bson` and `json` files from https://github.com/Apress/def-guide-to-mongodb/tree/master/9781484211830/The%20Definitive%20Guide%20to%20MongoDB

```
$ ls .
aggregation.bson  aggregation.metadata.json  mapreduce.bson  mapreduce.metadata.json  storage.bson  text.json
```

How can I import them into MongoDB?

I tried to import each of them as a collection, but failed:

```
$ mongorestore -d test -c aggregation 
2018-07-18T01:44:25.376-0400    the --db and --collection args should only be used when restoring from a BSON file. Other uses are deprecated and will not exist in the future; use --nsInclude instead
2018-07-18T01:44:25.377-0400    using default 'dump' directory
2018-07-18T01:44:25.377-0400    see mongorestore --help for usage information
2018-07-18T01:44:25.377-0400    Failed: mongorestore target 'dump' invalid: stat dump: no such file or directory
```

I am not sure if I specify the file `aggregation.bson` correctly, but the above command is what I learned from a similar example in a book.

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE**

In the following, why  did the first fail and the second succeed? Which command shall I use?

```
$ mongoimport -d test -c aggregation --file aggregation.bson 
2018-07-18T09:45:44.698-0400    connected to: localhost
2018-07-18T09:45:44.720-0400    Failed: error processing document #1: invalid character 'º' looking for beginning of value
2018-07-18T09:45:44.720-0400    imported 0 documents

$ mongoimport -d test -c aggregation --file aggregation.metadata.json 
2018-07-18T09:46:05.058-0400    connected to: localhost
2018-07-18T09:46:05.313-0400    imported 1 document
```

Comment: Are you aware that mongo has provided command line utilities [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) with the installation and that could maybe help you.

Answer (score 3):

```
mongoimport --db dbName --collection collectionName --type json --file fileName.json
```

---

**Update**:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>mongorestore -d test -c aggregation aggregation.bson
2018-07-19T10:28:39.963+0300    checking for collection data in aggregation.bson
2018-07-19T10:28:40.099+0300    restoring test.aggregation from aggregation.bson
2018-07-19T10:28:41.113+0300    no indexes to restore
2018-07-19T10:28:41.113+0300    finished restoring test.aggregation (1000 documents)
2018-07-19T10:28:41.113+0300    done
```

So I tried it and it worked fine for me do you have the file in your bin folder or maybe the command you used wasn't complete?

```
db.aggregation.find().pretty().limit(2)                                                                               
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("51de841747f3a410e3000001"),
        "num" : 1,
        "color" : "blue",                                                                                                       
        "transport" : "train",
        "fruits" : [
                "orange",
                "banana",
                "kiwi"
        ],
        "vegetables" : [
                "corn",
                "broccoli",
                "potato"
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("51de841747f3a410e3000005"),
        "num" : 5,
        "color" : "yellow",
        "transport" : "plane",
        "fruits" : [
                "lemon",
                "cherry",
                "dragonfruit"
        ],
        "vegetables" : [
                "mushroom",
                "capsicum",
                "zucchini"
        ]
}
```

Comment: @Tim check update, so apparently you do have to use mongorestore for bson. and I you maybe had the command a bit different

Comment: This is works..!! but what if I want to upload all collection in single click?.