# How to inspect a MongoDB backup database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I backup the server's MongoDB database with `mongodump`. Now I want to inspect the backup of the database.

The backup is in BSON and JSON formats:

```
$ ls <db-name>
contacts.bson  contacts.metadata.json ...
```

I want to run simple commands on the database, such as `db.contacts.find({})` and possibly also complex ones, such as aggregation and projection.

I could use `mongo-restore` which would overwrite the production database. I could transfer it to another machine and restore it too. Both strike me as non-agile.

Does MongoDB allow quick inspection of a database backup?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to query data in a database dump, load it into a running server and then query that server.

You can manually read a dump file, for example see [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/current/tutorials/bson-v4/#byte-buffers) for the Ruby BSON API. This isn't something the vast majority of applications do though.

Comment: Yes, both would work, and see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770498/how-to-import-bson-file-format-on-mongodb) for the first with `mongorestore`. I ended up spinning a new virtual machine with a snapshot of the whole server, which was very fast.